# Peut-on employer « un » et « de » de façon interchangeable devant l'objet d'une phrase négative ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, nombres, articles

Je lisais cette règle:

> In a negative construction, the partitive and indefinite articles
>   (singular and plural) change to de, usually meaning "(not) any":

Considérant cet exemple:

> Nous n'avons pas de voiture.
>
> We don't have a car.

Je me demande si c'est acceptable d'écrire:

> Nous n'avons pas une voiture.

Est-ce que c'est grammaticalement correct? Cela change-t-il le sens de la phrase?

---

I read this rule:

> In a negative construction, the partitive and indefinite articles
>   (singular and plural) change to de, usually meaning "(not) any":

Considering this example:

> Nous n'avons pas de voiture.
>
> We don't have a car.

I wonder whether it's acceptable to write:

> Nous n'avons pas une voiture.

Is this gramatically correct?  Does it change the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La règle est juste, et « nous n'avons pas une voiture » ne veut pas dire « *we don't have a car* ».

C'est certes correct grammaticalement, et employé pour insister sur *une* : « nous n'avons pas **1** voiture ». Généralement, pour dire « nous en avons **quatre !** » ensuite.

---

The rule is correct, and “*nous n'avons pas une voiture*” doesn't mean “we don't have a car”.

It *is* grammatical, though, and used to insist on the numeral “*une*”:

> *Nous n'avons pas **une** voiture* !
>   It's not **one** car we have!

Generally, one would carry on to say “*nous en avons **quatre !***” (“we have **four!**”).

Comment: Agreed, and strictly speaking the rule remains correct because *une* is not an indefinite article but a numeral in this case.

Answer (score 4):

La règle est en effet correcte, mais il y a tout de même un cas où l'on dira *pas un* (et en effet ça ne se dirait pas avec *voiture*), c'est lorsqu'on met l'accent sur l'absence de la chose en question, on sous-entend alors *Je n'en ai pas un seul*, comme dans la formule très commune ***je n'ai pas un sou***, ou ***pas un rond***.

---

The rule is indeed correct, but all the same there is a case where one would say *pas un* (and in fact it wouldn't be used with "car"), and that's when one puts the emphasis on the absence of the thing in question, or implies that "I don't have any...", as in the very common ***je n'ai pas un sou*** ("I don't have a penny").

Comment: *Je n'ai pas une minute à perdre* est aussi un bel exemple.

Answer (score 3):

En effet, ces deux négations sont différentes :

> **pas de voiture** >>> *No car* (0 voiture exactement)
>
> **pas une voiture** >>> *Not one car* (soit 0 voiture, soit plus d'1) (soit autre chose qu'une voiture)

---

Indeed, these two negations are different:

> **pas de voiture** >>> *No car* (zero cars exactly)
>
> **pas une voiture** >>> *Not one car* (either zero cars, or more than one, or something other than a car)