# Why is “de” used in “il n'y a pas de bus direct”?

Tags: négation, articles

I would need help in order not to mix up *de* and *le* or *un*

([What article can I use to refer to a thing correctly?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7321/what-article-can-i-use-to-refer-to-a-thing-correctly))

I came across this sentence

> Il n'y a pas de bus direct?

But I couldn't understand why *le* wasn't used (or for that matter *un*, if you don't want to refer to a particular bus). 
*Y avoir* doesn't seem to be in this list of verbs that are succeeded by «de» here http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/preposition_de_3.htm

Comment: “Pas un bus” would be possible, but it is rare and conveys emphasis: “not a single bus”. See http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/peut-on-employer-un-et-de-de-facon-interchangeable-devant-lobjet-dune/5687#5687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some situations, and negative sentences are one of them, where *de* is used instead of *des* (which is in this context the plural of *un*, there may be several direct busses).

> Il y a des bus directs.
>
> Il n'y a pas de bus directs.

(Note the plural for *directs* in both sentences).

Comment: Unless it's a misprint «direct» is not in plural. Sorry. But thanks for the tip

Comment: Actually, you would do the same with *“un”*. *“Il y a un bus direct”* becomes *“Il n’y a pas de bus direct”*.